# NVL / COALESCE equivalent in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to MongoDB. I'm using SpringBoot JPA with MongoDB

I want to convert below MySql query to MongoDB

```
select * from table_name where FIELD1=COALESCE( '0?', FIELD1) and FIELD2=COALESCE( '1?', FIELD2) and FIELD3=COALESCE( '2?', FIELD3)
```

I need to write it in @Query("some Mongo query")